# Error in if (nc == 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

I am running DIF in R and have the following problem after running the code. Please advise me on how I can solve this problem.

```
library("ordinal")

dat <- read.csv("aaa.csv",header=TRUE)
dat


G <- dat$group
X <- as.matrix(dat[,2:21])

N <- nrow(X)
n <- ncol(X)

library("mirt")

SPECS <- mirt.model('F = 1-5
PRIOR = (1-20, a1, lnorm, 0, 1),
(1-20,  d1,  norm, 0, 2),
(1-20,  d2,  norm, 0, 2),
(1-20,  d3,  norm, 0, 2)  ')

modpoly <- mirt(data=X,model=SPECS,itemtype='graded')
summary(modpoly)
coef(modpoly)

T <- fscores(modpoly,method="ML",
             full.scores=TRUE,scores.only=TRUE)
```

IT GIVES THE FOLLOWING ERROR

> Error in if (nc == 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: A comma after `F=1-5` perhaps?

Comment: No it does not work after adding the comma.

Comment: Please stop with the "guess my error in my data that you don't have" challenge. Post enough information to allow sensible efforts at debugging. You might start by saying what the symbol "DIF" is supposed to refer to. I don't see it in your code.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.